# Split page first vertically, then horizontal, and finally vertical again, for folding into eighths. Reflow?

Tags: boxes, minipage, multicol

I would like to make a letter sized document for folding into eighths for a pocket size pad to take notes and include references, for instance tasks for the day. I may use `org-mode` exporting eventually, but I'm not sure if reflowing text will be automatic enough to require negligible editing of layout.

Eventually I will include checklists and possibly skeleton tables, for instance so that I can jot down notes from my employer's weekly and daily schedule binders.

You can see in the LaTeX comments below my intention for a reflow of text, though this may not be realistic, just an ideal. Possibly, some panel pairs could be merged, for example some tables should not fit on an eighth, but rather a fourth of the sheet.

My first try was `twocolumns`. Next try was `multicols* ...{4}`, and then nesting two multicols, but text flowed off the page. In trying to cut a half-page in two horizontally, it seems I have to shift my strategy twoards `minipage` or `parbox`.

At this point, I hope someone with more experience and more vision could help with any advice, suggestions and/or partial solutions. Breadth over depth  is a plus, as I may have to adjust my strategy to the problem as I go.

Margins and separation of panels is a factor, because of folding.

```
\documentclass[landscape,
               % twocolumns
               ]{article}

% want content distributed in following order: 
% |----+----+----+----|
% |  1 |  2 |  5 |  6 |
% |----+----+----+----|
% |  3 |  4 |  7 |  8 |
% |----+----+----+----|
% on first side, and on second side: 
% |----+----+----+----|
% |  9 | 10 | 13 | 14 |
% |----+----+----+----|
% | 11 | 12 | 15 | 16 |
% |----+----+----+----|
% especially for printing and folding, so margins and panel separation
% should take this into account.

\usepackage[margin=9.0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength\columnsep{18.0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{4}

  \lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See _Die TEXnische Komödie_ 3/2010, pp. 27ff.

Comment: Not quite what you want (6 rather than 8) but see http://ctan.org/pkg/leaflet.

Comment: i believe this format is one of those described in peter wilson's ["glisterings" column, *tugboat* 31:3](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99glister.pdf).